# Finitely generated $R$-module as a sum of cyclic submodules

Tags: modules, finitely-generated

I know that  $M$ is finitely generated if there exist $a_1, ..., a_n$ in $M$ such that for any $x$ in $M$, there exist $r_1, ..., r_n$ in $R$ such that $x = r_1a_1 + \dots + r_na_n.$

But if I want to express this by its subsets is it correct to say, let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, then $M = \sum_{i \in I}M_i$ where $I$ is a finite set of integers and $M_i \subseteq M$ for every $i$?

Comment: I don't understand what your statement means.

Comment: Your second part is way weaker than finitely generated. You could pick $M_i=M$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven but is it correct to say? how I make it stronger?

Comment: Do you mean it is wrong? @Gae.S.

Comment: No, it is not correct to say. That is what I mean by it is way weaker. With your definition every module would be finitely generated, simply because $M=M$ (I picked $I=\{1\}$ und $M_1=M$).

Comment: @mathmusic No, I mean that I don't understand it. The obvious way to read it (with the $I$ being quantified by $\exists$ and the sequence of the $M_i$-s being quantified by $\exists$ as well) not only looks wrong, but it contains irrelevant details (like $I\subseteq\Bbb N$) while it's missing relevant pieces of information, like what the Hell the $M_i$-s are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be correct if you require each $M_i$ to be the submodule of $M$ generated by a single element $a_i$ of $M$.